# Inferrring correlation between two variables from two similar samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, t-test

I have a dataset that has both bad and good data. A sample of these two datasets are as below:

1. Bad

| ID | badness | protection% |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 50 | 5 |
| 200 | 30 | 100 |
| 300 | 60 | 20 |

2. Good

| ID | badness | protection% |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 0 | 0 |
| 201 | 0 | 100 |
| 301 | 0 | 50 |

I want to infer something that says if the protection % is low, badness score is high by comparing these two samples. Or there may not exist any relationship between badness and protection %. I think of hypothesis testing (t-test). But I couldn't figure out whether it is an appropriate method for this or not.

Comment: So these two samples are independent? There is no matching? What kind of variables are badness and protection? Range? Continuous?

Comment: Badness is defined by some other variable (in simple terms, how many people say it is bad). It is a discrete variable. It can have a range starting from 0 to infinite. Protection has a range from 0 to 100. The second sample is independent where I try to find those datasets that people say are good. The first and second sample has other variables which are similar in values. For simplicity, I did not mention them here.

Comment: When you say that badness is a discrete variable... but the values are in [0, inf)... is this some sort of frequency? Can you say that badness of zero means "no badness" and a badness score of 2 is twice as bad as a score of 1?

Comment: Yes, it is a count of some other variable in that dataset. For example, the number of people saying bad to sample of ID 100 is 50 (first row in bad dataset). Zero means no one said it is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming the two data sets are independent and you split them based on some measured variable rather than based on some partial results from said variables).
You could use a linear model, concatenate the two data sets and regress badness on protection and "group" (bad/good).

Example result in R (I've changed the "good" group a little bit to make the results more interesting, since right now the second set has all zero badness scores)

```
> dat=structure(list(ID = c(100L, 200L, 300L, 101L, 201L, 301L), badness = c(50L, 
30L, 60L, 0L, 5L, 3L), protection = c(5L, 100L, 20L, 0L, 100L, 
50L), group = c("bad", "bad", "bad", "good", "good", "good")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

> summary(lm(badness~group*protection,data=dat))

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)           57.7156     5.7714  10.000  0.00985 **
groupgood            -57.5490     8.6590  -6.646  0.02190 * 
protection            -0.2652     0.0979  -2.709  0.11356   
groupgood:protection   0.3152     0.1399   2.252  0.15313   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 7.071 on 2 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9704,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9261 
F-statistic: 21.89 on 3 and 2 DF,  p-value: 0.04401
```

Group "bad" has a slope of $-0.2652$ while group "good" has a slope of $-0.2652+0.3152 > 0$, however the difference is not statistically significant and neither is the slope.

Comment: What changes did you make in the "good" group with a "badness score" of zero? Reason for this? Also, why is there * in between group and protection in  ``summary(lm(badness~group*protection,data=dat))``? Should not it be ``+``?

Comment: @Shyamkkhadka small adders to badness for good group, I've added the data in the answer. The reason is that right now you have 3 records in group good with all zero values, which results in a very uninteresting model, you do not even need a model in this case. The * is used for estimating interactions between varibles, in this case a separate slope for each group.